# How to execute a curve slope correction in gnuplot?

Tags: function, gnuplot

I imported some data from a `.dat` file and obtained a curve. And I need to correct the slope of the curve. I executed a fit of linear regression that is supposed to correct it, however I can't seem to find a way to do so.

How can I execute an operation with the `.dat` file data and the function values?

Comment: Please provide more details. What is your data? What is your code so far? How does your graph look like?

Comment: The graph looks like a superparamagnetic curve, like this: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xinhua_Qi3/publication/255770502/figure/fig2/AS:298000648818699@1448060299681/Magnetization-curve-for-the-superparamagnetic-carbon-material-functionalized-with-SO-3.png
however the ends of my graph are not plateau/saturated. There's a linear interference that I have identified (with the fit function) and I need to remove it from the original data. But I already found a way of doing it, using my columns instead of the function values. Thanks for your help